# Download several files in background (iOS 7 only)

Tags: ios, ios7, download, background-process, nsurlsession

I'm currently developing a podcast application which will run only on iOS 7, and it has a feature that allows to synchronize and download recent episodes in background mode.

So it's clear with Synchronization, I implemented the
    `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler`
method and call the sync method in it, and when the sync is done I call completionHandler with `UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData`, or if it fails I call `UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed`. But when I run the download manager to start downloading all new episodes it can takes very long, depends on the network quality and file sizes, and the background mode just freezes in some point and suspend the recent download.

How the background downloading should be designed correctly?

Or maybe some link to tutorial which describes properly about the downloading files on background.

Comment: I'm tackling a similar problem. I wonder if AFNetworking 2.0 provides support for this.

Comment: Did you watch the WWDC 2013 session on this? The whole idea of background downloads is that they are efficiently managed by the system. Its not like a UNIX background download app that runs at 100% of the CPU is nothing else is going on. Apple is being stingy with the device, so its going to throttle things. As they stated, you will probably get better service if you download say 4 or 10 files at a time, not dribble one file request out then another. Note that if the device is not plugged in, the system is going to be real stingy with resources.

Comment: @DavidH , Thanks for the information, appreciate it. But do you have any ideas or thoughts about how can the downloading in the background be implemented in a right way?

Comment: I recently converted NSURLConnection code to use NSURLSession. It took me 2 or 3 days - longer than I would have expected. Its only does work in the foreground - I plan to support background transfers but I know from the WWDC video there are lots of details (and other posts here say the same). There is just no substitution for investing the time to read and watch Apple's offerings on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm observing the same behavior when downloading a lot of files.

It looks like it performs better, when you add all the downloads tasks to the background session when your app gets suspended, than to add a new download task every time one has finished and calls your delegate.

An other option would be to use the NewsstandKit. The background download runs very smooth but you have some restrictions like the 24h threshold and your app will be hidden in the newsstand.